Setting "Major Step" value of Line Chart
I am trying to set the value for the Major Step using Google Apps Script, but I am having a little trouble finding the correct parameter.
What I want to do is set the value for the highlighted section below.

I am able to update some of the other elements but I cannot find the correct parameter for this element.  I am using the .setOption method.
This is the code that I am using to do the update, the hAxis.ticks line is one attempt I have tried
I have also tried
.setOption("hAxis.interval", 5)

but that also didn't work

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName); // get the sheet
  var chart  = getChartByTitle(sheetName, sheetName);

  var options = chart.getOptions();
  
  options.series = {
          0: { color: lineColor }, // You can specify a color in hexadecimal format
        };

  var minValueX = sheet.getRange("P2").getValue();
  var maxValueX = sheet.getRange("O2").getValue();
  var minValueY = sheet.getRange("P4").getValue();
  var maxValueY = sheet.getRange("O4").getValue();

  // Generate the ticks based on the major step value
  var ticks = [];
  for (var i = minValueX; i <= maxValueX; i += 5) {
    ticks.push(i);
  }

  // modify the chart to handle the new values
  updatedChart = chart.modify()
    .setOption("vAxis.minValue", minValueY) 
    .setOption("vAxis.maxValue", maxValueY)
    .setOption("vAxis.textPosition", "none")
    .setOption("vAxis.gridlines", {"color": "transparent"})
    .setOption("hAxis.minValue", minValueX)
    .setOption("hAxis.maxValue", maxValueX)
    .setOption("hAxis.ticks", ticks)
    .setOption("backgroundColor", "white")
    .setOption("series", options.series)
    .build();

  try
  {
    // update the chart with the new values
    sheet.updateChart(updatedChart)
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    Logger.log('An error occurred updating the ' + sheetName + ' Speeding Curve Chart: ' + error.message)
  }


Does this answer your question? Apps Script version of changing a column chart's gridline major step spacing value?
